# Is there a way to fetch all the Stake Accounts of a given sol address?

Tags: web3.js, javascript

[image: Stake Accounts]

*It seems like there is no function from @solana/web3.js to call to fetch all the stake accounts of a given sol address.*

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `getProgramAccounts` on the stake program and the correct filter. It would probably look something like:

```
        await connection.getProgramAccounts(StakeProgram.programId, {
          commitment: 'confirmed',
          filters: [
            {
              memcmp: {
                offset: 44,
                bytes: '', // your pubkey, encoded as a base-58 string
              },
            },
          ],
        });
```

Here's an example from the CLI doing that: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b89ce94d33c4019bd332dbab0ca76ca5dbc5ceea/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1780-1789

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this, but Socean has an SDK that mimics the Solana Explorer codebase (and the same code @Jon posted above):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@soceanfi/solana-stake-sdk
Looks like they have a method, `findAllStakeAccountsByAuth` that does just what you want.

https://github.com/igneous-labs/solana-stake-sdk/blob/c9486f3c5835bde57cc6d56c0637a25900e2fb0c/src/fetch.ts#L37